# Hive generate adapter could not generate outputs

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am having issue generating the hive type adapter. No such output generated by the command line codes

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

or

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

final output massage is appaired as `Succeeded after 101ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)`

```
    import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
    
    part 'person2.g.dart';
    
    @HiveType(typeId:1)
    class Person {
      const Person({required this.age,required this.friends,required this.person});
      @HiveField(0)
      final String person;
    
      @HiveField(1)
      final int age;
    
      @HiveField(2)
      final List<Person> friends;
    }
```

my pubspec.yamel file

```
dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
      hive: ^2.1.0
      hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
      pdf: ^3.1.0
      path_provider: ^2.0.1
      open_file: ^3.1.0
      intl: ^0.17.0
    
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
      hive_generator: ^1.1.2
      build_runner: ^2.1.10
```

Comment: Is the file containing the `Person` class also called `person2.dart`?

Comment: yes file name is person2.dart